# (Fundamentals) Test class does not return anything after sysout

Tags: java, junit

Codewars. I've been trying to make this work for the last two hours. Beginner level.

The return statement is not working properly. For the record, this works in my IDE if I change the main method to a void main and replace the return statement with
`System.out.println(finalResult);` after the switch statement.

Solution I came up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BasicOperations { 
     static int finalResult;
  public static Integer basicMath(String op, int v1, int v2) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    op = userInput.nextLine();
    v1 = userInput.nextInt();
    v2 = userInput.nextInt();
      switch (op){
          case "+":
              finalResult=v1+v2;
              break;

          case "-":
              finalResult=v1-v2;
              break;

          case "*":
              finalResult=v1*v2;
              break;

          case "/":
              finalResult=v1/v2;
              break;

      }
      return(finalResult);
  }


}
```

Sample tests provided:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

public class SolutionTest
{
  @Test
  public void testBasics()
  {
    System.out.println("Basic Tests");
    assertThat(BasicOperations.basicMath("+", 4, 7), is(11));
    assertThat(BasicOperations.basicMath("-", 15, 18), is(-3));
    assertThat(BasicOperations.basicMath("*", 5, 5), is(25));
    assertThat(BasicOperations.basicMath("/", 49, 7), is(7));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
SolutionTest
testBasics
Log
Basic Tests
No line found
```

I am fully aware that the solution could be shorter and done in a smarter way. The main reason why I started doing codewars was to see how others do the solutions. First post ever on SO, so I'd appreciate feedback! Thank you for your time

Comment: How are you running the test?

Comment: @TimMoore in code wars, I am using the sample tests section provided by the author of the challenge. On my IDE, I made this:
```
 //testing
    @Test
    public void testBasics()
  {
    System.out.println("Basic Tests");
    assertThat(BasicOperations.basicMath("+", 4, 7), is(11));
    assertThat(BasicOperations.basicMath("-", 15, 18), is(-3));
    assertThat(BasicOperations.basicMath("*", 5, 5), is(25));
    assertThat(BasicOperations.basicMath("/", 49, 7), is(7));
  }
```

Comment: The `basicMath` method should use the `op`, `v1`, and `v2` values that are passed to it, rather than trying to read them from `System.in`.

Comment: Also, this may not be required to pass the test, but `finalResult` should be a local variable rather than a static member.